# Call SQL linked sever function or stored procedure from select statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-server, openquery

I have a stored procedure which calls a lookup function as part of the SELECT statement:

```
-- PX type
CASE WHEN coi.SKU_ID like 'PX%' THEN
    [GG].dbo.PXStockInventoryLookup(coi.SKU_ID)
ELSE
    0
END
```

In the production environment, the `GG` database is on a different server so a linked server is used to reference it. Trying to call the function using 4 part naming gives this error:

```
Remote function reference 'UATLINK.GG.dbo.PXStockInventoryLookup' is not allowed, and the column name 'UATLINK' could not be found or is ambiguous.
```

After some research I found out about using `Dynamic SQL`, `OPENQUERY` and `sp_executesql` in a local function:

```
DECLARE @ParamDefinition as nvarchar(100)
SET @ParamDefinition = N'@Result int output'
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000);
SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY( [UATLINK], ''SELECT  [GG].[dbo].[PXStockInventoryLookup](''''' + @param + ''''')'')'
exec sp_executesql @sql, @ParamDefinition, @Result = @sii output
return @sii
```

This code works fine in isolation, but I can't create it a function as SQL doesn't allow me to call a function from within another function.  I can create is as a stored procedure but then I can't call it from the select statement!

I'm just going round in circles trying to solve this, any ideas?

Comment: You can't use dynamic sql in a function.

Comment: Explanation for Sean's statement [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9607970/243373)