# Incorrect syntax near begin in sql server while creating function

Tags: sql-server, function, t-sql, sql-function

I am stuck with a very petty issue that I am unable to resolve.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fntblPsmHaendlerDailyCostsinfodump(@pDateString varchar(8), @HaendlerID int, @TableName varchar(100),@CountryID int)
RETURNS table
AS BEGIN
RETURN select top 10 * from tblcountry
END
GO
```

This is giving me an error -

> 'Incorrect syntax near begin'.

I am not able to identify why it is giving the error.

Answer (score 5):

Correct syntax for [inline UDF](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189294%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

> Inline user-defined functions follow these rules:
>
> - **There is no function_body delimited by BEGIN and END.**
> - **The RETURN clause contains a single SELECT statement in parentheses.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fntblPsmHaendlerDailyCostsinfodump(
     @pDateString varchar(8),
     @HaendlerID int,
     @TableName varchar(100),
     @CountryID int)
RETURNS table
AS
RETURN (select top 10 * from tblcountry);
GO
```

`BEGIN` and `END` are necessary for multistatement UDFs.

Comment: I have multiple lines in function thats why i used begin and end.i have

Comment: @TanuJain I mean multistatement. Of course `SELECT` could be broken to multiple lines for readability

Comment: No i mean i have to do processing inside function like creating dynamic query and then executing it using EXEC(@SQL). Without begin and end how should i do it.

Comment: @TanuJain You cannot execute dynamic SQL inside function. Period. Check [Call dynamic SQL from function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607935/call-dynamic-sql-from-function#9607970)