# SQL Recursive index finding query

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have query that list all tables in my DB with their respective indexes:

```
SELECT 
     TableName = t.name,
     IndexName = ind.name,
     IndexId = ind.index_id,
     ColumnId = ic.index_column_id,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     ind.*,
     ic.*,
     col.* 
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 
     ind.is_primary_key = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0 
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

I obtain an output like this:

[image]

`TableName -> contain Table names in DB
ColumName -> contain Index column name for each table in DB`

My target is to plot for each `"TableName" + "ColumnName"` TOT number of record and last (max) ColumnName value.

Basically that's the output in tab format I'd like to obtain:
[image]

Do you have any idea how to recursively generate this result in a single query?
Thanks!

Comment: *"plot for each "TableName" + "ColumnName" TOT number of record and last (max) ColumnName value."*: I have no idea what that means. Can you include in your question a table as you would like the output to be?

Comment: Just added. Basically from the main query I need to iterate per each TableName and per each ColumnName and obtain TOT number of record and last value.

Comment: @user3925023 - Each table is having primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this may be fast enough to run in your setup, and was my best try. There are problems involving type of columns and `max()` aggregate, which dictates that the `max_value` should be an `varchar`.

Just make sure you `use your_database_name` before creating and executing this procedure, which for the application invocation is similar to a single query.

```
create proc stp_generateColInfo as

declare
 @tablename varchar(1000),
 @columnname varchar(1000)

set nocount on

create table #TMP_DDL (
    TableName varchar(1000), 
    ColumnName varchar(1000),
    TOTAL int,
    MAX_VALUE varchar(8000)
);

INSERT INTO #TMP_DDL
SELECT 
     TableName = t.name,
     ColumnName = col.name,
     0 as TOTAL,
     '' as MAX_VALUE
FROM 
     sys.indexes ind 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.index_columns ic ON  ind.object_id = ic.object_id and ind.index_id = ic.index_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.columns col ON ic.object_id = col.object_id and ic.column_id = col.column_id 
INNER JOIN 
     sys.tables t ON ind.object_id = t.object_id 
WHERE 
     ind.is_primary_key = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique = 0 
     AND ind.is_unique_constraint = 0 
     AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0


declare cs cursor local static forward_only for
    select TableName, ColumnName from #TMP_DDL

open cs
fetch next from cs into @tablename, @columnname
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
begin
    exec('
    declare @total int, @max_value varchar(8000)
    select @total=count(*), @max_value=max(IsNull(' + @columnname + ',0)) from ' + @tablename + '
    update #TMP_DDL set total=@total, max_value=@max_value where TableName=''' + @tablename + ''' and ColumnName=''' + @columnname + ''''
    )
    fetch next from cs into @tablename, @columnname
end

close cs
deallocate cs

set nocount off

--Add joins here to select additional columns :)
select * from #TMP_DDL

go
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid creation of table?I don't have rights to do so.Thx

Comment: see this: https://jasonstrate.com/2013/05/21/security-questions-what-permissions-are-required-to-create-temporary-tables/ I think every user has right to create temporary tables!

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have any idea how to recursively generate this result in a
>   single query?

It is not possible.

You need to call a dynamic sql statement

```
SET @sql = 'SELECT @MaxID = MAX('+@ColumnName+') FROM '+@TableName
```

separately for every line of your resultset and as [functions cannot contain dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9607970/2224701) it is not possible to write it as one select statement in SQL Server. You cannot call dynamic SQL or [a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1656804/2224701) for every single row separately in one query.

In Oracle there are commands like [BULK COLLECT and FORALL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2012/12-sep/o52plsql-1709862.html) that allow combining resultsets with row-by-row processing, but I am not aware that anything like that exists in SQL Server.